# jQuery get each checkbox value onclick

Tags: jquery, foreach, onclick, each, laravel-7

Literally, my checkboxes is placed in @foreach loop and contains data from Eloquent. And I need to get value of checkbox clicked.

For example:

```
@foreach ($lots as $lot)
<td>
    <input type="checkbox" id="get-{{$lot->id}}" value="{{$lot->id}}" class="get">
</td>
@endforeach
```

And jQuery script:

```
$(".get").each(function(i){
    $(this).on("click", function(){
        var lot_id = $(".get").val();
        alert('Работает' + lot_id);
        
    });
});
```

I don't know how to get id of one checkbox if it's id is generated and lots can be various.

Answer (score 1):

Use the following code

```
$(".get").on("click", function(){
    var lot_id = $(this).val();
    alert('Работает' + lot_id);        
});
```

Answer (score 0):

use vanilla javascript you can `querySelectorAll` to get value and attributes

```
document.querySelectorAll('.get').forEach((ele)=>{
 ele.addEventListener('click', (e)=>{
   var id = e.target.value;
   console.log(id);
 });
});
```

Using jQuery, try something like this

```
$(document).on('click', '.get', function(){
  var id = $(this).val();
  console.log(id);
});
```